# Adding timestamp to redshift copy from hdfs

Tags: hive, amazon-redshift

I am new to Redshift , I am using a connector written in spark which does the job of exporting data from hive table by select * from query to redshift table .
Now , as by the data in redshift is always appended , I was wondering if it is possible to add time stamp to the data appended to redshift without modifying the original hive table data , so that a simple sort on time stamp would generate the latest output.

Comment: You want to create always new table on Redshift that contains data from hive query with additional actual date of inserting? You are inserting data via S3 and COPY or how? So issue is how to get easily structure of the target only from query and append there column with 'datetime default sysdate' ?

Comment: yeah  @Dolfa  , I am inserying via s3 , you are right issue is how to get easily structure of the target only from query and append there column with 'datetime default sysdate